# Program keeps printing one extra line then what the user inputs

Tags: cs50

I'm having some trouble trying to build a pyramid out of "#" for mario.c in problem set 1. My program seems to be having some trouble with handling input.

**I get these errors:**

```
:( handles a height of 1 correctly
    expected ""#"", not "" #"\n"##""
:( handles a height of 2 correctly
    expected "" #"\n"##"", not ""  #"\n" ##"\n..."
:( handles a height of 8 correctly
    expected ""       #"\n" ...", not ""        #"\n"..."
:( rejects a height of 9, and then accepts a height of 2
    expected "" #"\n"##"", not ""  #"\n" ##"\n..."
```

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("How many rows for the pyramid?\n");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 8); //This loops until the user input 1 - 8 rows
    
    for (int row = 0; row <= height; row++) //This says to print a new row until it reaches the user inputted height
    {
        for (int spaces = (height - (row + 1)); spaces >= 0; spaces--) //This formula prints less spaces as more rows are printed
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int hashes = 1; hashes <= (row + 1); hashes++) //This formula prints more hashes as more rows are printed
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints an extra line of hashtags creating a pyramid which is 1 greater in height than the user input. You can see this in the error message you get:

`:( handles a height of 1 correctly expected ""#"", not "" #"\n"##""`

Hence, the output of your program is  `#\n##` which equates to

```
 #
##
```

The required output for a height of 1 is:

```
#
```

To fix your issue, you have to iterate through your code one lesser time than you do currently for any number. Hence, perhaps consider changing the condition: `row <= height;` in your for loop.

Consider changing the comparison to just `<`. By doing this, the code inside the for loop will run one lesser time.